# Fixing ApplicationID in aws EMR serverless or any aws resource via terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, emr-serverless

Currently EMR Serverless applicationID changes every time there is a configuration change, so our dashboards need to be regularly updated. Is there a way to fix applicationID or any other way in which we can get historical view of the resource that is changed. The tricky part is metric filtration is only possible via applicationID among useful params:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-Serverless-UserGuide/app-job-metrics.html

There is no way currently. Any suggestions how to proceed.